# Are single points or rectangles of area $0$ simple closed curves?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I was solving the following problem:

> Show that $\oint_C{-x^2ydx+xy^2dy} > 0$ around any simple closed curve $C$.

I began with applying Green's Theorem:
$\oint_C{-x^2ydx+xy^2dy} = \iint_R{y^2+x^2}$

$y^2+x^2 \geq 0$, so $\iint_R{y^2+x^2} \geq 0$.

Note that I still need to prove that $...>0$, not $...\geq 0$.

The only time $... = 0$ is when $R$ has an area of $0$, which means it's a point or a rectangle with width or height of $0$.

So, if I can say that such $R$s aren't simple closed curves, than I can adjust $\geq$ to $>$.

**Are single points or rectangles of area $0$ simple closed curves?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  According to the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem), all Jordan curves (also known as simple closed curves) divide the plane into two regions - an **inside** and an **outside**.

A single point has no "inside" in this sense.

Comment: @TMM, thanks!  I shall dedicate my first moderation task to you!